# seriel number generator, starts from 0 everytime i start the app

Tags: c#

I need a serial number to be stored in data base with a record when I click a button, so far I did this and it works it generates serial number ,but the problem when I exit the app and start again the serial number starts from 0 again and that doesn't work because in the database its primary key. so I need it to continue where it left off. im sorry if im not explaining well

```
public static class SequentialNumber
{
   private static int id=0;
   public static string GetId()
   {
        id++;
        return id.ToString();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I think the question doesnt fit stackoverflow and noone will write code for you. You need to search tutorials on how to connect with your database through c#.

Comment: You can fetch the last stored serial from the database and insert with new row after increasing it by one. A simple way is to use identity column in your table if you are using SQL Server.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis I don't need anyone to write me a code, and I am already connected to database

Comment: @VikramKumar do you mean I can fetch the id that the user have entered? ill try that

Comment: @carl Correct! Get the last inserted serial number before inset, increase it and then insert with new record. Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

**You have multiple approaches to solve this issue**

1. Set Your Primary Key column to [Auto Increment column](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) that'll give you your serial number in DB only no need to write And c# code for that.
2. Store last serial number on application Exit then Read last available serial number from DB and load
3. Use file instead of Database

**Note:-** if the file where counter is stored is be deleted then counter will start from 0

```
public static class SequentialNumber
{
    private static int id=0;
    public static string GetId()
    {
        if(id==0)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(File.ReadAllText("count.txt"),out id);
        }
        id++;
        File.WriteAllText("count.txt", id.ToString());
        return id.ToString();
    }
}
```